# Gradle build fails on enabling data binding with multi modules

Tags: android, kotlin, nullpointerexception, android-databinding

Adding dataBinding { enabled = true } fails the gradle build with following error. The project itself doesn't have any databinding code yet.

Gradle Versions :

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0-alpha10'

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.3-rc-2-all.zip

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeProdDebugResources'.

  > Error: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tried to invalidate and restart didn't work.

```
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

Comment: It's a weird issue but finally was able to resolve. One of the layout files has fileformat set to bomb encoding. Once I removed that things started working

Answer (score 0):

You need use same version used on your `gradle version` like follow:

**project.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext.gradle_version = '3.3.2' // declare this variable

    repositories {
        ...
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$gradle_version" // use this classpath with variable declared above
        ...
    }
}

allprojects {
    ...
}
```

**app.gradle**

```
...

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt' // use kotlin kapt

android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
    }
    buildTypes {
        ...
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true // enable databinding
    }
}

dependencies {
    ...
    kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:$gradle_version" // use this dependency with variable declared on your project.gradle
}
```

Comment: I did but still the same error. I even tried to use the relase version of gradle 3.3.2 still the same. The thing is I have a muti module project with resource coming from a library module.